# How to replace a particular string in java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a CSV file like

```
Data
Dun&BradStreet
Dunkin & Donut
```

Here Data is the 'header' of the column.

I am using the encoding and replacement as

```
 String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(data[i], "UTF-8");
 String data = encodedUrl.replaceAll("%2B","+");
```

Desired Result

```
Data
Dun&BradStreet
Dunkin+%26+Donut
```

Output

```
 Data
 Dun%26BradStreet
 Dunkin+%26+Donut
```

How to keep '&' if there are no spaces when '&' is present?
Any help  is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to put this information in a URL?  If so, the `&` should be encoded per http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt unless you are using it in a special way (like separating name-value pairs).  If you are not putting it in a URL, why are you using URLEncoder.encode on it?

Comment: @lreeder : Yes I am going to put in an URL. So that is why I need to know how to do the encoding without replacing '&' as in the first case? I appreciate any help.

Comment: if you want to put the first value also in the URL it also needs to be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like so,

```
String in = "Data\nDun&BradStreet\nDunkin & Donut";
System.out.println(in.replace(" & ", "+%26+"));
```

Output is "Desired Result" -

```
Data
Dun&BradStreet
Dunkin+%26+Donut
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one if there are one or more times spaces before and after &.

here `\\s+` represents one or more times spaces. Read more about [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
String str = data[i].replaceAll("\\s+&\\s+", "+%26+");
```